# tkinter locking up with sys.exit

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I was following along in a youtube tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zf-b2JVZs7g

When we got to `sys.exit(0)`

The Python shell seems to be responding but the window I create locks up instead of closing.  The other weird thing is that when I run the debugger, the program operates as expected.

```
#Python 2.7.8
#Idle 2.7.8
#Tkinter 8.5.15

import sys
import Tkinter
import turtle
from Tkinter import *


def main():
    root = Tk()

    root.title("Draw!")
    root.geometry("800x800")

    cv = Canvas(root, width=600, height=600)
    cv.pack(side=LEFT)

    t = turtle.RawTurtle(cv)
    screen = t.getscreen()
    screen.setworldcoordinates(0,0,600,600)

    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = BOTH)
    screen.tracer(0)


    def quitHandler():
        print ("Goodbye")
        sys.exit(0)
        ##raise SystemExit
        ##exit()


    quitButton = Button(frame, text="Quit", command = quitHandler)
    quitButton.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def clickHandler(x,y):
        t.goto(x,y)
        screen.update()

    screen.onclick(clickHandler)

    def dragHandler(x,y):
        t.goto(x,y)
        screen.update()

    t.ondrag(dragHandler)


    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In the comments of the video there are two things that stick out to me but I can't figure out why `sys.exit(0)` isn't working for me like it worked for him:

1. He's using Python 3
2. Other people are having this same problem and there aren't any answers that I can see.

My guess is that it's a version problem but (as a n00b) I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: The details of Python shutdown _have_ changed from version to version, even within 3.x.  I personally would put root.destroy() but not sys.exit() in a quit handler, and would let Python exit normally after mainloop() and main() call return.  Since printing 'goodbye' does not print to the gui, and could fail (if you run the app with pythonw on windows), I would put the print _after_ the main() call.

Comment: Thanks Terry! I added this information to the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the line `root.destroy()` to your `quitHandler` function. It will clean up the Tkinter process that is otherwise left behind. I tested it and that fixes the issue for me.

*(Code removed)*

## Update

From Terry Jan Reedy's comment:

> The details of Python shutdown have changed from version to version,
>   even within 3.x. I personally would put root.destroy() but not
>   sys.exit() in a quit handler, and would let Python exit normally after
>   mainloop() and main() call return. Since printing 'goodbye' does not
>   print to the gui, and could fail (if you run the app with pythonw on
>   windows), I would put the print after the main() call.

So it would be

```
def quitHandler():
    root.destroy()
```

and `print` at the very end of the code.

Comment: Just for clarity though, is this a version problem?  or why does his work and mine doesn't.  There were other things that didn't work for me that worked for him.

Comment: He's on a Mac, so Tkinter would be implemented completely differently from on Windows. Not including root.destroy leads to unpredictable behavior, so the different implementations give different results. Sometimes the program will clean up after you automatically. But he should have included it.

Comment: I guess I forgot to ask what OS you're using.

Comment: Ah ok.  I'm using windows 7.  So am I correct in assuming that for any loop, you should always terminate it explicitly?

Comment: You mean whenever using `mainloop`? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it very easily like this:

```
def quit():
       import sys;sys.exit()

widget = Button(root,text="Quit",width=1,fg="red",command=quit).grid(row=1,column=1)
```

If you use this code you can customize your bottom more.

Answer (score 0):

```
def quitHandler():
    print ("Goodbye")
    root.destroy()
    sys.exit(0)


quitButton = Button(frame, text="Quit", command = quitHandler)
quitButton.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

This will work fine.